# Calculate coordinates (x,y) of a ball at any given time

Tags: java, math, geometry, 2d

I'm making a simulation of a ball in the a 2D space, drawing its path.

I'm using `g.fillOval(x,y,height,width);` to draw the ball

The ball is affected by three forces : Gravity, Wind and shot-power, it also has a starting angle.

This picture demonstrates what i mean

[image]

Knowing that the ball starts from `x=11 y=360`

i want to change the value of x and y according to ball's position at any time given and under the mentioned forces..

an equation that would do that should be something like

```
x += Angle Power Gravity Wind
y -= Angle Power Gravity Wind
```

Answer (score 2):

The equation is well known if you've studied physics.  It's Newton's law in 2D:

```
sum(forces) = mass * acceleration
```

This is really three equations, since force, acceleration, velocity, and displacement are all vector quantities.

You'll simplify by assuming 2 dimensions.

Gravity will always act in the negative y direction in your simplified view; no x-component.

Wind can vary in direction, so you'll need to say how it evolves with time or assume that it's constant for the period you're studying.

Mass of the ball is fixed.  It's big enough where quantum effects can be ignored.

Velocities are much smaller than the speed of light, so relativistic effects can be ignored.

You'll need to know a bit about calculus - do you?  These are differential equations in time.  You'll start with initial conditions and either integrate in closed form or step the equations forward numerically in time steps to see how the motion evolves.

Let's make it easy: constant wind in the negative x-direction.

I don't know what "shot power" is, but I'm betting you'll know the initial velocity of the ball as it's shot out of the cannon.

So here are the variables you'll need:

```
ax = acceleration of the ball in the x-direction
ay = acceleration of the ball in the y-direction
fx = wind resistance force
fy = gravity
vx = velocity of the ball in the x-direction
vy = velocity of the ball in the y-direction
ux = displacement of the ball in the x-direction
uy = displacement of the ball in the y-direction
t  = time
m  = mass of the ball
```

And here are the equations that relate them:

```
ax = -fx/m
ay = -fy/m
ax = dvx/dt = first derivative of vx w.r.t. time
ay = dvy/dt = first derivative of vy w.r.t. time
vx = dux/dt = first derivative of ux w.r.t. time
vy = duy/dt = first derivative of uy w.r.t. time
```

You'll need initial conditions:

```
ux = 0 at time = 0
uy = 0 at time = 0
vx = vx0 at time = 0; it's greater than zero if you shoot to the right
vy = vy0 at time = 0; it's greater than zero if you aim the cannon up
```

It's easy to solve if you substitute:

```
d^2(ux)/dt^2 = -fx/m
d^2(uy)/dt^2 = -fy/m
```

Integrate once w.r.t. time:

```
dux/dt = -(fx/m)*t + c0
duy/dt = -(fy/m)*t + c1
```

Integrate again to get the position of the ball as a function of time:

```
ux = -(fx/m)*t^2/2 + c0*t + c3
uy = -(fy/m)*t^2/2 + c1*t + c4
```

Your initial conditions help with the constants:

```
ux(0) = c3 = 0
uy(0) = c4 = 0
```

and

```
vx(0) = c0 = vx0
vy(0) = c1 = vy0
```

**So here are the final equations for the position of the ball of mass m after you shoot it with initial velocity (vx0, vx0) into a head wind fx and gravity fy:**

```
ux = (vx0-(fx/m)*t/2)*t
uy = (vy0-(fy/m)*t/2)*t
```

You can shift the answers relative to any starting point (ux0, uy0):

```
ux = ux0 + (vx0-(fx/m)*t/2)*t
uy = uy0 + (vy0-(fy/m)*t/2)*t
```

If you shoot the cannon at an angle theta from the horizon, and the ball has initial speed v, then the initial conditions become:

```
(vx0, vy0) = (v*cos(theta), v*sin(theta))
```

If the wind is calm, this solution still works: just set fx = 0.

This solution assumes that the head wind is constant and isn't a function of the velocity of the ball.  If it is, the equations are nonlinear and you have to solve them numerically.

As noted in the comments, you can make the head wind term more complex, too.

You can make these equations (and their solution) more complex by including more physics effects:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ballistics

Comment: Usually, the force on a resting object in a gas streaming with velocity `v` is C*v*|v|, where C contains the exposed surface, shape, Reynolds number and possibly some other factors. So it is quadratic in v and not constant. In the considered case, one would have to use as v the relative velocity, velocity of wind minus velocity of the ball. So if the ball moves in the same direction and with the same velocity as the wind, there is no wind force. If the wind is only applied to the x coordinate, this is still integrable. But for generality, use numerical integration.

Comment: yes, i know that.  i think i was clear about my simplifying assumptions and why i chose them.  the op cited "shot power", so i didn't think the full monty was appropriate.  "This solution assumes that the head wind is constant and isn't a function of the velocity of the ball. If it is, the equations are nonlinear and you have to solve them numerically." - I never said "linear function of velocity".

Comment: Ok, so it is weak wind that does not change the y component of the velocity very much. One still can solve manually `d/dt vy=-C*(vy-wy)*|vy-wy|` (for vy > wy) as `1/(vy(t)-wy)-1/(vy(0)-wy)=sign(vy(0)-wy)*C*t`, `vy(t)=wy+(vy(0)-wy)/(1+C*|vy(0)-wy|*t)` and finally `y(t)=y(0)+wy*t+sign(vy(0)-wy)*1/C*ln(1+C*|vy(0)-wy|*t)`.